# Как удалить NewPP limit report из текста который спарсил?

Tags: python, html, парсер, requests

Я спарсил текст из из сайта и удалил в нем все теги которые не нужны, но если вывести текст в нем будет отчет о работе , мне его надо удалить или в параметрах функции прописать чтоб не показывался репорт

```
import csv
import urllib.request as urllib2
from datetime import datetime
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.lurkmore.com/view/Dragon_Tattoo'
res = requests.get(url)
html_page = res.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
text = soup.find_all(text=True)

output = ''
blacklist = [
    '[document]',
    'noscript',
    'header',
    'html',
    'meta',
    'head', 
    'input',
    'script',
    # there may be more elements you don't want, such as "style", etc.
]

for t in text:
    if t.parent.name not in blacklist:
        output += '{} '.format(t) ##получение текста , который спарсил 


text = output.replace('\\', '')
print(text)
```

Вот что мне выдает print(text). Мне надо удалить все начиная с NewPP limit report

```
Dragon Tattoo - The LURKMORE Wiki ♥  donate bitcoins :  1JsbEn3pVJcWKGE24hiV5eJSGSTzNT2rTw  ♥  donate litecoins :  LTfZmMMiNDVx4uWgntmBYubYHjoVqvxsYZ  ♥ 
 
 
 Dragon Tattoo From LURKMORE wiki Jump to navigation Jump to search  start content  A rant in reply to someone looking for pictures of dragons for his tattoo idea.
 
 yeah fuck yeah dragons, all over my body. yeah i fucking want one dragon for each of my limbs, ad then one on my head. i'm gonna look so fucking cool with my dragon tattoo fucking dragons. no fuck that i want two dragons, one on one side of my back and one on the other. fuck yeah dragons they're so cool with their wings and shit and they have teeth. dragon teeth. fuck yeah i want a dragon on my entire back and have its wings as my shoulder blades ad shit because dragons you know? fuck yeah i can't believe no one ever had the idea of putting a fucking dragon on his back before this is gonna be fucking awesome. i'm gonna show up in the tattoo parlor and be like fuck yeah dragon, right fucking here, and the dudes gonna be like holy shit no way really a dragon? and i'll be like fuck yeah dragon WOOOOO. and he'll be like fuck yeah dragon WOOOOO and tattoo that shit all over me, and then when he finished he'll be like awwww awesome bro, there's a fucking dragon on your body, i've ever done this before, put a dragon onto someones body but then you came in here like WOOOO with all that adrenaline and i was like WOOOO too because it was like fucking contagious and fucking dragons it was sick bro i can't wait to show people my work so they can be like fucking dragons WOOOO too!
 and then i'll walk outside and every chick ever will be drawn to me like i'm wearing a fucking gallon of axe and i will be wearing a fucking gallon of axe and they'll be like holy shit you smell so good and HOLY FUCK WOOOOO a dragon ON YOU, what the fuck, where did you ever get the idea to put a dragon on your back and they'll be so fuckig horny from seeing all the wings and fucking teeth of the fucking dragon oh and fucking horns, they're horny because of the fucking horns of the WOOOOO fucking dragon and all this time i'll be like fucking attracting girls like i'm wearing a gallon of axe, which i am because why the fuck not? fucking dragons and i think that even fuckig dragons deserve to smell good and they'll be all on my balls, the dragon, not the chicks, no wait the bitches, not the dragon because a fucking dragon on my nuts would hurt but fucking bitches sucking on my balls would be sick and they'd be licking the axe off my balls because bitches love that shit and fucking dragons, on my fucking body you know and horns and teeth and wings and shit and they'll be like fuck me you dragon and i'll be like fuck yeah, in the middle of the street fucking these bitches with my dragon and they'll all be orgasms all over the place fucking dragons WOOOOO
 and then i'll get home fom this mad sex session and all my bros will be like dude where did yo-HOLY A FUCK A DRAGON and they'll take out like lawn chairs and shit to fight the dragon but i'll be like yo guys cool it its only me, i got a dragon tattooed on me so now you were confused when you saw the dragon it was actually me, and then they'll all be like HOLY FUCK DUDE thats so cool, its a fucking dragon, and one guy will be like dude look at all the teeth and wings and horns and tails and shit dude this is so fucking sweet i bet you get mad pussy begging to bang you because you have a fucking dragon on you and dude it looks so real you had us all fooled we had picked up fucking lawn chairs and shit to fight this fucking wack ass dragon who came into our bros back lawn but then we find out its only you with this fucking dragon on you. and i'll be like yo dude its so true you get bomb ass pussy with this fucking dragon because it has wings and teeth and horns and tails and legs and shit and all that shit combined with the axe is like fucking ... fucking... fucking... amazing for them so they just sit on your cock and i mean sit, they dont even need to insert it and they're coming like a waterfall so they just take their fat asses and sit on it like its a seat and then they come they're so fucking horny from it its amaxing. and they're like dude i knew you were wearing axe i could smell it isn't it so bomb tight? and i'm like yeah these bitches were all up on it because of the axe and the arms and legs of the dragon not to mention the wings teeth and horns that were all fucking up on this dragon that this dude tattooed on me and yo he was so fucking pumped to put this dragon on me it was so fucking awesome he was like WOOOOO and i was like WOOOOO and then we were all like fucking dragons
 
  
NewPP limit report
Cached time: 20210328163823
Cache expiry: 86400
Dynamic content: false
CPU time usage: 0.004 seconds
Real time usage: 0.158 seconds
Preprocessor visited node count: 1/1000000
Preprocessor generated node count: 4/1000000
Post‐expand include size: 0/2097152 bytes
Template argument size: 0/2097152 bytes
Highest expansion depth: 1/40
Expensive parser function count: 0/100
Unstrip recursion depth: 0/20
Unstrip post‐expand size: 0/5000000 bytes
 
 
Transclusion expansion time report (%,ms,calls,template)
100.00%    0.000      1 -total
 
  Saved in parser cache with key wiki_lurkmore:pcache:idhash:4166-0!canonical and timestamp 20210328163823 and revision id 15418
  
 
Retrieved from " https://www.lurkmore.com/w/index.php?title=Dragon_Tattoo&oldid=15418 " 
 Category :  Copypasta  end content  Navigation menu Page actions Page Discussion View source History Page actions Page Discussion More Tools Personal tools Log in Request account Navigation Main page Recent changes Random page quick links Memes Memes and terms 4chan Camboys Camgirls Cross-dressers Traps Camwhores the lurkmore group Fap Overload the overchan v3 intern3ts chansluts male general tranchan textchan social Twitter GreedBox Toplist 
 
 
 
 Search    Tools What links here Related changes Special pages Printable version Permanent link Page information  end of the left (by default at least) column   Page last modified 07:14, 24 June 2009. Content is available under the CC BY-NC license. Direct links back to the article must be included. About the LURKMORE Wiki
```

Answer (score 0):

Уже исправлено

```
regex = re.compile(r'(NewPP).*$', flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
text = re.sub(regex, '', text)
```